# Overlaying image on scenePhase when sheet is open

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewmodifier

I've made a `ViewModifier` for my app so that when it goes into `.background` phase it shows a splash of an image. However, when a `.sheet` or a `.fullScreenCover` is presented it doesn't seem to be triggering the modifier or detecting scenePhase changes.

I've [seen that you have to pass the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72620322/1086990) from presentation to presentation which works for a 1-2 views, but if I want it to operate on the ViewModifier is it possible? Or is this a bug?

I feel like having to pass either `.maskView()` to every screen or passing the `@Environment()` or `.environment()` to *every* view too seems wrong for Swift.

#### Main view

```swift
struct TestOverlay: View {
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show sheet") {
            showSheet = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Button("Hide sheet") {
                showSheet = false
            }
        }
        .maskView()
    }
}
```

#### Modifier

```swift
struct MaskingViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @State private var currentPhase: ScenePhase = .active
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
                .blur(radius: currentPhase == .active ? 0 : 5)
            Color(.systemBackground)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .opacity(currentPhase == .active ? 0 : 0.4)
            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                .resizable()
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .frame(width: 180, height: 180)
                .opacity(currentPhase == .active ? 0 : 1)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .animation(.default, value: currentPhase)
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            switch phase {
                case .active:
                    currentPhase = .active
                case .inactive:
                    currentPhase = .inactive
                case .background:
                    currentPhase = .background
                @unknown default:
                    currentPhase = .active
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Extension

```swift
extension View {
    func maskView() -> some View {
        return modifier(MaskingViewModifier())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `onChange(of: scenePhase)` does not get triggered this is indeed a bug. (Edit: I think it only works on the `App` struct level.)

Note that you do not have to pass environments for every child view, but only when presented as `sheets`.

The masking of the view will however never hide the sheet as the sheet is presented above the view modifier. The order of applying `.sheet` does not matter unfortunately.

One solution would be to fall back to `UIKit`, and present the blur on an overlaid `UIWindow`.

You could use something like this:

```
... // some View

  var window: UIWindow?

  var body: some View {
    someView
      .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
          // some logic if blur should be showed:
          UIApplication.shared.presentOnOverlayWindow(SomeBlurView())
      }
    }

...


extension UIApplication {
  /// Returns a window to wich a strong reference needs to be kept for the duration of the presentation of the view controller.
  /// Otherwise the window is deallocated and removed from the view hierarchy.
  static func presentOnOverlayWindow<V: View>(_ view: V) -> UIWindow? {
    let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
      ?? UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first { $0.activationState == .foregroundInactive }
      ?? UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first

    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
      return nil
    }

    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    window.rootViewController = rootViewController

    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    rootViewController.present(UIHostingController(rootView: view), animated: true)
    return window
  }
}
```

This is only presenting the blur, but you will need to also remove it through the stored `UIWindow` ref.